# What edition of Empire Builder do I have?

Tags: crayon-rail-games

My family has an old edition of Empire Builder by Mayfair games, and the box I have isn't listed on Boardgame Geek's edition list.

I found [an image of the box on that site](http://boardgamegeek.com/image/457416/empire-builder). It is pre-fourth edition, as it doesn't have Mexico in it, and very little of Canada. The rulebook lists a copyright of 1982. It comes with a bunch of metal trains, the rule book is black and white, and the cards are black and white front with red 'M's on the back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linked picture is the [first edition](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameversion/194574/first-edition)

The 1982 copyright suggests it may be a later printing of that edition (2nd edition was 1984)

Comment: Thank you very much! I've been curious about this for a while, and no one was answering. 50 reputation well spent.